# How to retrain model using old model + new data chunk in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm currently working on trust prediction in social networks - from obvious reasons I model this problem as data stream. What I want to do is to "update" my trained model using old model + new chunk of data stream. Classifiers that I am using are SVM, NB (e1071 implementation), neural network (nnet) and C5.0 decision tree.

Sidenote: I know that this solution is possible using RMOA package by defining "model" argument in trainMOA function, but I don't think I can use it with those classifiers implementations (if I am wrong please correct me).

Comment: you should provide a small sample data set with your existing code for other users to experiment with .

Comment: I didn't see the point of providing data sample, because this problem has nothing to do with the structure, size or any other characteristic of the data - actually it is not related to the data at all.

Comment: You can update your model by providing a new dataset. I don't see the point of providing a code example, because this problem has nothing to do with the structure, size or any other characteristic of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to strange SO rules, I can't post it as comment, so be it.
Classifiers that you've listed need full data set at the time you train a model, so whenever new data comes in, you should combine it with previous data and retrain the model. What you are probably looking for is [online machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning). One of the very popular implementations is [Vowpal Wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit), it also has bindings to R.